# body background-image change is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, background-image

i am trying to change background image using javascript by clicking on a linked image which is working fine without any problem in IE but it is not working in firefox... can u please help and correct me what is wrong???? the code is below:

**Javascript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var w=screen.width
var h=screen.height

if(w==1152) {
var backImage = new Array(); // don't change this

var i = 0;
backImage[0] = "images/patterns/background-1152x-bellow.png";
backImage[1] = "images/patterns/background-1152x-mellow.png";
backImage[2] = "images/patterns/background-1152x-mix-1.png";
backImage[3] = "images/patterns/background-1152x-mix-2.png";
backImage[4] = "images/patterns/background-1152x-sellow.png";
backImage[5] = "images/patterns/background-1152x-yellow.png";

function changeBGImage(whichImage){
if (document.body){
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+backImage[whichImage]+")";
    cookie.set('bgImage', whichImage, 365);
}}
} else if(w==1280) {
var backImage = new Array(); // don't change this

var i = 0;
backImage[0] = "images/patterns/background-1280x-bellow.png";
backImage[1] = "images/patterns/background-1280x-mellow.png";
backImage[2] = "images/patterns/background-1280x-mix-1.png";
backImage[3] = "images/patterns/background-1280x-mix-2.png";
backImage[4] = "images/patterns/background-1280x-sellow.png";
backImage[5] = "images/patterns/background-1280x-yellow.png";

function changeBGImage(whichImage){
if (document.body){
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+backImage[whichImage]+")";
    cookie.set('bgImage', whichImage, 365);
}}
}
</script>

<a href='javascript:changeBGImage(0)' ><img src='images/patterns/yellow.png' style='width:26;height:26;'></a>
<a href='javascript:changeBGImage(1)' ><img src='images/patterns/blue.png' style='width:26;height:26;'></a>
<a href='javascript:changeBGImage(2)' ><img src='images/patterns/green.png' style='width:26;height:26;'></a>
<a href='javascript:changeBGImage(3)' ><img src='images/patterns/red.png' style='width:26;height:26;'></a>
<a href='javascript:changeBGImage(4)' ><img src='images/patterns/brown.png' style='width:26;height:26;'></a>
<a href='javascript:changeBGImage(5)' ><img src='images/patterns/grey.png' style='width:26;height:26;'></a>
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML in your question; the PHP is irrelevant. And what is `w`?

Comment: sorry for that .. and updated question please have look about w..    var w=screen.width -------- 
var h=screen.height

Comment: What is supposed to call your `changeBGImage()` function? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Can you check that document.body exists at the moment it is called? You could try to wrap this script in an onload function or inside the body. Also try with single quotes inside url:  `"url('"+backImage[whichImage]+"')";`

Comment: working in IE but not working in firefox @Rober

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.body.style.background = "url("+backImage[whichImage]+")";
```

not backgroundImage

Comment: Which version of firefox? I tested on my mac and it worked fine. Do you have a link to the page or something?

Answer (score 0):

The image url has to go as a string in CSS, so you need additional quotes (single quotes in this case):

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backImage[whichImage]+"')";`

Those double quotes are only making it a string for javascript, but not for CSS.